# Calling back a view managed by the UINavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have somes UIViewsControllers managed by a UINavigationController, but in a specific moment a call a UIViewController that I don`t want to be managed by my UINavigationController, then a I triggered a modal segue to that UIViewController, in that view a placed a buttom that call back my last UIVIewController (managed by the UINavigationController) by a modal segue, but when that view did load again, it doesn't show the header bar with the back buttom...

Some idea about that?

Comment: I think you have some problem with understanding Navigation controllers. It's like a stack can you pop an element in stack if it's not there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> by a modal segue, but when that view did load again, it doesn't show the header bar with the back buttom...

This description means you're creating a new instance of the view controller and presenting it on its own.

What you should be doing is presenting a new navigation controller with this new view controller as the root. Or, dismissing the first modal (to go back to the original nav + view controller).

Comment: Now I triggered the button to the root of the UINavigationController and it works! tks...